# How to delete number one by one when click on button delete jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have `button` like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.my_button').click(function() {

    //var value = $(this).val()
    var number = $(this).val();
    var value = $('#input').val($('#input').val()+number);
    //console.log( typeof value.val());
    var str = value.val();
    //console.log(str.length);
    if(str.length === 2){
        //event.preventDefault();
        $('.my_button').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

    }

});

$('#delete').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).val();
    var value = $('#input').val($('#input').val()+number);
    //console.log( typeof value.val());
    //var str = value.val();
     $('#input').val("");
     ///value.remove().text();
});

});
```

**Here is my html file:**

```
        <div class="btn">
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="1">
                1</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="2">
                2</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="3">
                3</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="4">
                4</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="5">
                5</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="6">
                6</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="7">
                7</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="8">
                8</button>
          <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="9">
                9</button>
    
        </div>
    
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button id="delete" name="delete">delete</button>
```

How to delete the number from **textarea** one by one whenever I click on `delete` button.

When **textarea** is empty prevent button delete not clickable.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no "delete" button... And there is no "delete" script attempt.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstand the community policy. I have updated my question.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't mean to get free code writing service. I just need some help.

Comment: That's fine. Just pointing out how the site works. You can use [String#slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) based on the `length`  of the current value string to get a new value with one less character

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, now I get the point. How about delete number from textarea one by one when I clicked delete button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#input').val(value.substr(0, value.length - 1));` this will get the value of textarea then delete `1` character from it and set that value inside textarea area.Also , you can use `attr("disabled", true)` whenever length of textarea value is `< 0`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_button').click(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
    var value = $('#input').val($('#input').val() + number);
    var str = value.val();
    if (str.length === 2) {
      $('.my_button').attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
    }
  });

  $('#delete').click(function() {
    var value = $('#input').val() //get textarea value
    //get string from 0 to end and do -1
    $('#input').val(value.substr(0, value.length - 1));
    //set disabled..
    $('#input').val().length > 0 ? $(this).attr("disabled", false) : $(this).attr("disabled", true)

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="1">
                1</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="2">
                2</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="3">
                3</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="4">
                4</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="5">
                5</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="6">
                6</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="7">
                7</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="8">
                8</button>
  <button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="9">
                9</button>

</div>

<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button id="delete" name="delete">delete</button>
```

Comment: Thank for your respond, this solve my problem.